# Problem with yecc grammar

Tags: erlang

I'm currently writing a small parser in erlang, using yecc, and have encountered some problems. The problems occur when I'm parsing rules with 'lbrack' in it. The following rule
is an illustration of my problem:

```
program -> 'char' 'ident' 'lbrack' 'int_constant' 'rbrack' 'semi'
```

It compiles ok, but when I'm trying to parse the following tokens:

```
[{char,1},
 {ident,1,1,t},
 {lbrack,1},
 {int_constant,1,10},
 {rbrack,1},
 {semi,1}]
```

the parser crashes with

```
{error,
 {1,parser,["syntax error before: ","lbrack"]}}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried with the following yecc file, yt.yrl:

```
Nonterminals
program.

Terminals
char ident lbrack int_constant rbrack semi.

Rootsymbol
program.

program -> 'char' 'ident' 'lbrack' 'int_constant' 'rbrack' 'semi'.
```

with your input and it worked fine. It didn't return anything, well `'$undefined'`, but that is as it should be as my example doesn't return anything. Note that none of your terminal symbols need to be quoted as they are just normal atoms with "ordinary" names.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know if my other rules interfered, but when I renamed 'lbrack' to '[' (In both the lexer and my yecc grammar) it worked.

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference as yecc detects interference between rules and disallows it. No ambiguity is allowed.